# systemSound no longer working with upgraded Xcode 4.5.2 using ARC

Tags: ios, xcode

For playing quick sounds I prefer SystemSound over AudioPlayer because load time is quicker. But now I have upgraded to Xcode 4.5.2 and using ARC my code to play audio snippets no longer works. See full code below. The error I get is from the following line:  AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)filePath, &soundID); I get red error with the following error message : Cast of Objective type NSURL to C pointer type CFURL (aka const dtruct). Any ideas how could replace this line ??`

```
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath],   @"/click.mp3"];

SystemSoundID soundID;

NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path isDirectory:NO];

// here is the problem line 
     AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)filePath, &soundID);

AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
```

Comment: Try `AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)filePath, &soundID);`

Comment: @RoboticCat - thanks for trying but I tried that and got linker error messages - any other ideas ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ARC, you need to use __bridge for toll free bridging between Foundation and Core Foundation.

Try this:

```
CFURLRef url = (__bridge CFURLRef)filePath;
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(url, &soundID);
```

Comment: Thanks - but this brings up 3 Linker Errors as follows: Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID", referenced from:
      -[ViewController sound2:] in ViewController.o
  "_AudioServicesPlaySystemSound", referenced from:
      -[ViewController sound2:] in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: No I didn't - I had <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h> - Just added  AudioToolbox and all works fine - WELL DONE and THANK YOU !!!